# How do i make a custom Sort? (Order by online/offline Status)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, vbulletin

I'm pretty new to HTML, PHP and what not, but I have a basic understanding, I realize that there are obviously features for Ordering by Numeric/Alphabetical. However the feature I want I really can't find anything about, nor search the right term to find a guide for what I'm looking for

Basically I have a custom  stream page for clan members, above each stream is text and an image *stream status: online/offline*, this feature works 100% when the person streams it will change from online to offline

However all of the streams are muddled up, a stream that is online is found at the bottom of a page or in random places

I want it to bring streams that are currently online to the top, is that even possible?

```
<?php

$channelName = htmlspecialchars($_GET['channel'], ENT_QUOTES);

$clientId = '';             // Register your application and get a client ID at http://www.twitch.tv/settings?section=applications
$online = 'online.png';     // Set online image here
$offline = 'offline.png';   // Set offline image here
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$clientId), true);

if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];

    echo "$channelTitle is <img src='$online' alt='Online' /> playing $currentGame";
} else {
    echo "$channelName is <img src='$offline' alt='Offline' />";
}

?>
```

Is what i'm using to pull the stream status &

```
<A NAME="SADMAN"><center><font size="3" color="red"><span style="color:#FFFFFF">Konvict</span> - Sadmanwhosane - <span style="color:#CEE3F6">Stream status:</span> <img src="http://teamewix.com/stream.php?streamuser=sadmanwhosane87"></font>
```

is all im doing to show it

Comment: Depends on how you get that data. Is it stored in a database? Use `ORDER BY`. Is it stored in a PHP array? Use `usort()`. Or maybe even JavaScript.

Comment: Well right now i'm not storing it or anything, it's just plain HTML, as i said in my main post, im pretty new to all of this & still learning, so i basically just used standard HTM

Comment: I've basically made a custom Page on my vbulletin website, Which allows PHP/HTML, i've made the banner Images functions to show the streams when clicked & hide when clicked again & then literally just made the code to show the banner & accept the function

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PnOjXIP.png is what i have at the moment, the code for it is a cluster...I think i might need to completly re-do the code, but im unsure of the best way to do it

1) it shows streams unordered - I want it to bring online streams to the top

2) it is html/php & built into a vbulletin custom page

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery Table Sorter:

link is [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Comment: That's all well & good, but i'm not actually using a table, i want it to automatically bring "online" streams to the top, not just by clicking a function?

Comment: thank you for clarification, but do you have a guide or anything?

Answer (score 0):

So i'm guessing that the page isn't refreshing? then you use ajax to get the latest data and then update the details of the page.

Link to [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (for asynchronously getting data)

Link to [jQuery html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (for updating the html with the new data)

If you know php and jquery well then this will be an easy task and the links will lead you the way. But if you don't then that's another story. Goodluck!

---

**EDIT**

My above answer is async, no page refresh involved.

You have a database with users who are online and offline right? You use `jQuery ajax` to find out who's online and offline. Then when you have the data. You use `jQuery html` to change the elements of the page.

If you just want to position them depending on their status during page refresh then you use basic `php` and `html`. Use `arrays`. 3 arrays to be exact.

Array1 - All teams

Array2 - Online Teams

Array3 - Offline Teams

You just get all online teams from Array1 and transfer it to Array2 and all offline teams from Array1 to Array3.

Then echo the teams from Array2 first. Then Array3 last.
But again this is on page refresh. If you don't want any page refresh follow my first answer.

---

**EDIT2**

your code:

```
if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];

    echo "$channelTitle is <img src='$online' alt='Online' /> playing $currentGame";
} else {
    echo "$channelName is <img src='$offline' alt='Offline' />";
}
```

to this code:

```
if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];

    array_push($OnlineTitleArray,$channelTitle);
    array_push($OnlineCurrentGameArray,$currentGame);

} else {
    array_push($OfflineArray,$channelName);
}

foreach($OnlineTitleArray as $key => $val){
    echo $val.' is <img src='.$online.' alt=\'Online\' /> playing  '.$OnlineCurrentGameArray[$key];
}

foreach($OfflineArray as $key => $val){
    echo $channelName.' is <img src='.$offline.' alt="Offline" />';
}
```

So you need the arrays to put the data in using [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) then [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to display the data. Hope this helps. And check this if you find it helpful

Comment: Hi thanks for trying, but this still doesn't answer my question, i want the streams to Order automatically by Online/Offline status, when one comes online it will bring it to the top

Comment: I see what you mean, but right now im not using Databases for it...

http://teamewix.com/stream.php?streamuser=sadmanwhosane87

I'm literally just asking if X person is online through the Twitch.tv API, it's not pulling information from my database or anything, the guys at teamewix made the API check, problem is i can't see how they've done it, so i can only Pull online/offline status from their stream.php & incorperate it into my own page

Comment: how do you get the status and how do you process the status? it would be better if you show codes. That way other users can help you better.

Comment: @DanielStarmer check `Edit2`

Comment: I mean you've definitely helped me, but i'm still kinda confused as to how to get the Data to show, genericly to get my stream status i just do

<im src="http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=isypie">

So what would i do now? As i would usually stack the streams like

<im src="http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=user1">
<im src="http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=user2">
<im src="http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=user3">